# Dual Mode Bluetooth (BLT/BLE) -To-UART Bridge Module Recommendation

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller

I need a module to server as a Bluetooth-UART/SPI bridge for an MCU, that has to have the  following characteristics:

1. Programmable
2. Fast bring-up (a known manufacturer with straight-forward set-up and programming)
3. Dual Mode - BLE / non-BLE
4. non-BLE transfer rate of at least 3Mb/s
5. UART / SPI transfer rate that will not be a bottleneck, so at least 4Mb/s
6. example applications for serial connection over Bluetooth (so I can easily and reliably send and receive chunks of data between the MCU and a phone via the Bluetooth module)

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with dual-mode; I've used Adafruit's LE UART Friend in the past which has great documentation and support, but obviously it doesn't really meet your requirements. If you haven't already seen it, you could try taking a look at [this selection](https://www.mouser.com/Embedded-Solutions/Wireless-RF-Modules/Bluetooth-Modules-802151/_/N-6l7pg?P=1z0y3upZ1yvspn3Z1yvrdq3Z1y9fncxZ1ywteprZ1yxgjx0) and set the filters; the only two modules I see that fit your requirements are the Panasonic ENW-89823A2JF and ENW-89823C2JF. My guess is there's probably more out there tho.